# How to rename voice channel using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a voice channel in my server which serves to display the date, and I am creating a bot which should update it every minute. I am having problems getting the bot to rename the bot though, as I am not very experienced in discord.py. Here is the code:

```
import asyncio, os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

async def background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        #Rename Voice Channel
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

client.loop.create_task(background_task())
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VoiceChannel.edit()` ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicechannel#discord.VoiceChannel.edit)).

As you can see it has a `name` parameter, which sounds like what you need. You can edit a channel using

```py
await vc.edit(name="new-name-goes-here")
```

You can get a `discord.VoiceChannel` instance of the channel using [`get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel).